# Two redirects after each other in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form on frontend page that after submiting should redirect to a page that API returns but I must redirect first to a thank you page and then after some seconds should redirect to the page that the API returns.

this is so far what I have tried but it only waits for the second refresh.

```
if(isset($result_array['status']) && $result_array['status'] == true)
{
    $autologin_url = $result_array['data'] . PHP_EOL;
    $signup_result = true;
    header("refresh: 5; url = fakeurl.com/thanks.php");
    header("refresh: 15; url = $autologin_url");
}
else
{
    echo $result;
    $signup_result = false;
    header('location: fakeurl.com/?report=signup_error');
}
```

Comment: Place your second redirect on your `thanks.php`.

Comment: @brombeer I have eneded up doing that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what *brombeer* meant by the redirect:

```
if(isset($result_array['status']) && $result_array['status'] == true)
{
    $autologin_url = $result_array['data'] . PHP_EOL;
    $signup_result = true;
    header("refresh: 5; url = fakeurl.com/thanks.php");
}
else
{
    echo $result;
    $signup_result = false;
    header('location: fakeurl.com/?report=signup_error');
}
```

And Paste this in your thanks.php Script:

```
header("refresh: 15; url = $autologin_url");
```

Comment: But the `thanks.php` will not know `$autologin_url` - this value would need to be passed as a GET parameter or stored into the session.